# Android SQL retrieve and set multiple rows

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

Hello I have setup a small SQL query which simply returns the users email address when two ID's match up. Now I have a very simple problem where now I want to return another row e.g. persons name but I'm little stuck on setting up the selection and then setting the text on another activity. In my current code I can set one value but some guidance would be nice.

Handler.java

```
public String getContactDetails(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String name = "";

    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT email FROM person_list WHERE person_id=?", new String[] {id + ""});

        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email"));

            // how can I get another row?


        }
        return name;
    }finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Main Activity...

```
MyDatabaseHandler myDatabaseHandler = new MyDatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext(), null, null, 1);

String email = myDatabaseHandler.getContactDetails(id);
```

Thanks
It's more than likely something really simple.

Answer (score 0):

To call next data, you can use **cursorObject.moveToNext()**. This method will return false if the cursor is already past the last entry in the result set.

[Cursor Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html,)

```
public String getContactDetails(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String name = "";

    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT email FROM person_list WHERE person_id=?", new String[] {id + ""});

        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
              do{
                  name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("email"));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext()); // more to next data.
            }
        }
        return name;
    }finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so do I make another cursor.getString with the other row which has e.g. persons name and then how do set the information?